# How to add a column to an excel in rails using Axlsx gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx

I have few column names defined in my choices and I am adding it to the sheet as a first row but, one of the column should not be present all the time, it should vary conditionally, so I want to add a specific column based on some condition.

Here is my code
**sheet.add_row choices, style: style_shout**

NOW, How should I add a **column** to the sheet?

Comment: If the first example on the project page doesn't help please clarify why. https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/examples

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

adding first row with column names, then second row with column values

```
sheet.add_row ['col 1', 'col 2', 'col 3', 'col 4', 'col5']
sheet.add_row [1, 2, 0.3, 4, 5.0]
```

and depending on the conditions you want you can modify as required, for example:

```
  #Hide the 5th column
  sheet.column_info[4].hidden = true
```

you could encapsulate this within a condition to hide or display a column